# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Using When Condition For Branch Name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline and I would like to deploy my application according to the git branch. Even branch information in Jenkins and when condition matches, Jenkins says: *"skipped Deploy to dev stage due to when conditional" It is same as for test branch when the branch is test. How should I fix this issue?

Note: Branches to build in project configuration settings set like */develop , */test , */master and and Jenkins can trigger when I push my code to dev or test branch.

```
stage('Deploy to dev'){
        when{
            beforeAgent true
            anyOf{
                branch "origin/develop"
            }
        }
    stage('Deploy to staging'){
        when{
            beforeAgent true
            anyOf{
                branch "origin/test"
            }
        }
```

Console Output

```
           +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
            Seen branch in repository origin/develop
            Seen branch in repository origin/master
            Seen branch in repository origin/test
            Seen 3 remote branches
             > git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
            Checking out Revision 5ebda79eb3a50a578786e75587f7d92dfc399122 (origin/develop)

           [Pipeline] { (Deploy to dev)
           Stage "Deploy to dev" skipped due to when conditional

           Stage "Deploy to staging" skipped due to when conditional
```

Comment: Remove `origin/` and use `branch 'develop'`, `branch 'test'`.

Answer (score 2):

is variable BRANCH_NAME defined?
This variable is used by the `when` step.

Did you use the (github) multibranch plugin that sets this variable automatically?
Do a println to see if it is defined.

to set this variable, here is what I do in my build stage

```
  stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def commit = checkout scm
                    // we set BRANCH_NAME to make when { branch } syntax work without multibranch job
                    env.BRANCH_NAME = commit.GIT_BRANCH.replace('origin/', '')

                    //actually build ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: GIT_BRANCH variable defined and the value is GIT_BRANCH=origin/develop.No I did not install github multibranch plugin. Can I use this variable with when condition? But why my current script is not working and I need to do extra settings. Could you please update your answer with GIT_BRANCH?

Comment: My project item is Pipeline by the way not a Multibranch pipeline

Comment: You need to define the environment variable BRANCH_NAME . pipeline dsl step `when` does not care about GIT_BRANCH variable. You could set DARK_VADOR variable, pipeline dsl step wont care neither. it only expects BRANCH_NAME. `when` step does not work if `BRANCH_NAME` variable is not define. I don't know if there is a jira issue about that but I agree it's not user friendly

Comment: so when condition onyl accept BRANCH_NAME variable, am I correct?

Comment: Pipeline: Multibranch plugin installed but when ı  echo "Branch name: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}" , it returns null.

Comment: I think BRANCH_NAME  is not working for normal pipeline projects

Comment: When a pipeline is executed by the multibranch pipeline job, the env.BRANCH_NAME variables is defined. The when step works. When you execute a pipeline job that was not triggered by multibranch pipeline job, the env.BRANCH_NAME is not defined, the when step does not work. By defining the env.BRANCH_NAME directly in your pipeline as I showed in the answer I gave to your initial question, the when step works